# How do I remove a Moiré pattern from such a polar plot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, data-analysis, antialiasing, radial

How do I remove a Moiré pattern in a polar plot generate by Plotlib?

I tried resizing the figure, but while improving a bit, once I increased too much the size the RAM fails.

I tried cv2 for image antialising, but to no avail.

Any hint?

[image: Polar plot]

Comment: You could try to create the plot with a higher figsize and/or dpi. Note that your post is missing the necessary code, turning answering your post into a blind guessing game.

Comment: Increasing the distance between the rings, is it an option?

Comment: @JohanC, Indeed the only way was to increase the figure size by using a workstation with higher RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot with increased resolution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).